# How do I expose a variable to html.html.twig?

Tags: 8

I want to add different css styles to my edit/create pages. The easiest way I can think to do that would be to add 'edit/create' classes to the `body` tag when the node is being edited or created by adding them to html.html.twig. `hook_node_access()` has the variable `$op` which defines the current operation, so the question is how do I expose that variable to my html.html.twig template so I can add the classes only when update/create?

Comment: Im from D7 and never worked with twig but maybe there is a class that u can inject in order to pass variables to tiwg? Pretty sure that D8 would have something to do this

Comment: Just so you know, edit/create pages uses the Admin theme (the default admin theme is `Seven`) so if you wish to modify edit/create pages, you will need to edit the admin theme and not your website's theme.

Comment: They _can_ use the admin theme but my users prefer the page to look like the site when editing so in configuration `Use the administration theme when editing or creating content` is turned off.

Comment: @Naidim interesting, ok, then you will be fine using your website's theme. The answer is in the link I provided. The two answers will give you the same result, so pick whichever you like.

Comment: I know how to add the class, but how do I expose the $op variable to only add the class conditionally?  e.g. in html.html.twig `set body_classes = [ op ? 'edit', ...`

Comment: Or in `THEME_preprocess_html()`  `$variables['attributes']['class'][] = $op;`?